# Adding the results of multiple functions

Tags: function, python-3.x, mapping

Using python 3.3

Stumbled upon another problem with my program. Its the same solar program. Again i decided to add more functionality. Its basically ad-hoc. I'm adding things as i go along. I realize it can be made more efficient but once i decide its done, I'll post the whole coding up.

Anyway, i need to add the results from multiple functions. Here's a part of my coding:

```
def janCalc():
    for a in angle(0,360,10):                                           #angle of orientation
        for d in days(1,32,1.0006630137):                               #day number of year
            for smodule in equation():                  #equation() function not shown in this coding
                total_jan+=smodule              #total_jan is already defined elsewhere              
        avg_jan=total_jan/(60*(1.0006630137*31))                
        ratio_jan=avg_jan/5.67
        calcJan=(ratio_jan*4.79)
        yield calcJan
        total_jan=0                     #necessary to reset total to 0 for next angle interval    

def febCalc():
    for a in angle(0,360,10):
        for d in days ((1.0006630137*31),61,1.0006630137):
            for smodule in equation():
                total_feb+=smodule
        avg_feb=total_feb/(60*(1.0006630137*28))
        ratio_feb=avg_feb/6.56
        calcFeb=(ratio_feb*4.96)
        yield calcFeb
        total_feb=0

#etc..............
```

Is there anyway to add the yield of each function? 
for e.g: calcJan+calcFeb+.....

I would like to get the total results under each angle interval and then dividing by 12 to get the average value per interval. Like so:-

0   degrees---->total/12

10  deg    ---->total/12

20  deg    ---->total/12

30  deg    ---->total/12

........

360 deg    ---->total/12

If you need more info, let me know.

### ADDENDUM

The solution was essentially solved by @jonrsharpe. But i encountered a bit of a problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Solar program final.py", line 247, in <module>
    output=[sum(vals)/12 for vals in zip(*(gen() for gen in months))]
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Solar program final.py", line 247, in <listcomp>
    output=[sum(vals)/12 for vals in zip(*(gen() for gen in months))]
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Solar program final.py", line 103, in janCalc
    for smodule in equation():
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Python\Solar program final.py", line 63, in equation
    d=math.asin(math.sin(math.radians(23.45))*math.sin(math.radians((360/365.242)*(d-81))))
NameError: global name 'd' is not defined
```

I've isolated it to:

```
for d in days ((1.0006630137*31),61,1.0006630137):    
    for smodule in equation():
```

It turns out i can't reference a function from inside a function? I'm not too sure. So even my original coding did not work. I assumed it was working because previously i had not defined each month as a function. I should have tested it out first.

Do you know how to get around this?

Comment: What does "I only know how to get the yield per function but don't know how to interact them in the manner i want." mean? Also, try to factor out all those "magic numbers" in your code.

Comment: I shouldn't have included that. It is confusing. What i meant to say was, I just know how to refer to one function, but not how to refer to multiple functions for my equation. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't define `total_feb`; you certainly *can* "reference a function from inside a function". Where is the full error traceback?

Comment: just posted the traceback error.

Comment: The problem is that that function `equation` doesn't work; it's unrelated to the code you have posted so far! You should test the function separately before calling it from other code; you may need to open a new question (with all the appropriate information) if you can't make it work separately. First I would suggest you get rid of any `global` variables and pass functions the arguments they need explicitly, this will make `NameError`s easier to find and fix.

Comment: ok. i'll see what i can do from my end. I'll post another question in a day or two if i still can't solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example to demonstrate how to combine multiple generators:

```
>>> def gen1():
    for x in range(5):
        yield x

>>> def gen2():
    for x in range(5, 10):
        yield x

>>> [sum(vals) for vals in zip(*(gen() for gen in (gen1, gen2)))]
[5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
```

Or, written out long hand:

```
output = list(gen1())
for index, value in enumerate(gen2()):
    output[index] += value
```

You can modify either version to include a division, too, so your case would look something like:

```
months = [janCalc, fabCalc, ...]

output = [sum(vals) / 12 for vals i zip(*(gen() for gen in months))]
```

Comment: Hey jon, sorry for bothering you again. i encountered abit of a problem. Your coding is fine. But it is on my part that is faulty. I've made an addendum to the problem. please check it out.